# mongoose setCurrentLogger does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to change the `mongoose` console log printing using the `setCurrentLogger` function as described [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Logger.html#.setCurrentLogger) and in the tutorial for older mongo driver [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/tutorials/logging/#custom-logger:3f3af53408cff75953b33723c0b061bb). I didn't find any instructions to do that with `mongoose` only with the native `mongodb` driver.

In order to test it, I just tried changing only the printed `msg`:

```
var mongoose        = require('mongoose');
var MongoLogger     = require('mongodb').Logger;
var MongooseLogger  = mongoose.mongo.Logger;

MongoLogger.setCurrentLogger(function(msg, context) {
    console.log('aaaaaa', context);
});

MongooseLogger.setCurrentLogger(function(msg, context) {
    console.log('aaaaaa', context);
});
```

But it doesn't seems to work, I'm still getting the full error stack priting on console, instead of the expected `aaaaaa`.

The question is, how to change the logger function in mongoose like the `setCurrentLogger` function described for the native driver

Answer (score 0):

I noticed it doesn't work unless you set the logger *after* connecting. And you need to set the log level too:

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Logger   = Mongoose.mongo.Logger;

Mongoose.connect(uri);

Logger.setLevel('debug');
Logger.setCurrentLogger(function(message, context) {
  console.log(message);
});
```